# What is the evidence against a variable gravitational constant?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, dark-matter, physical-constants, dark-energy

I understand that our main supporting evidence for dark matter is the anomalous speed of objects orbiting around the edges of distant galaxies. Is there a reason why dark matter solves this problem better than say, the strength of gravity simply being stronger in the region? My idea is that maybe these galaxies don't seem to be large scale attractors, but it also seems to me that they could be attracted themselves to areas of space where gravity is EVEN stronger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dark Matter vs Modified Gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319575/)