# Has there been any attempt to model gravitational fields to explain dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter, modified-gravity

I've often wondered whether [dark matter](https://home.cern/science/physics/dark-matte) is a by product of the mixing of gravitational fields.

When we look at electromagnetic fields we can observe harmonics and [intermodulation effects](https://www.rfpage.com/how-does-intermodulation-distortion-occur).  This is something of which I have extensive experience in the radio and photonics fields, e.g. beat frequencies, etc.

However, looking at research databases such as [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=gravity%20intermodulation&btnG=) there appears to have been no attempt by physicists to model gravitational field intermodulations.

Has it ever been attempted to model gravitational fields intermodulation in a similar manner to electromagnetic fields thus explain dark matter?

Comment: Note that the equations governing gravity are non-linear, so superposition is complicated to say the least.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6561/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319575/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Are you asking for answers in the context of general relativity or modified gravity? (If the former, the links are not duplicates but it is quite clear that the idea is not viable)

Comment: @Sten I am asking if anyone ever modelled gravitational waves interacting over long distances in an attempt to explain dark matter. I'm not referring to gr or mg, I'm asking a general question. Such modelling is extremely relevant in electromagnetics but there seem to be no literature on such with regard to gravity. It seems the question was either not understood or not liked. Maybe it's a taboo question but directing me to two questions on diffewrent topics and telling me to get lost is not really that helpful.